# Delete rows with certain conditions in string Python

Tags: python, twitter, text

I'm doing research on a certain keyword of Twitter messages, using the Twitter search API for Python.

Now I have a large CSV file, consisting of messages containing this keyword, but also with the keyword in the username. So these messages aren't about the keyword, the keyword just happens to be in the username.

This is my current code but it doesn't work:
What I'm trying to do:

@XXXXXXXXXX tweeted: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

I try to delete all lines for which the keyword Amsterdam is in the part XXXXXX

```
import csv


input = open('oefendeleted.txt', 'rb')
output = open('oefendeleteduser.txt', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output)
for row in csv.reader(input):
    input.row.split('@')[1].split['tweeted'][2]
    if not str[1].contains('Amsterdam'):
            writer.writerow()
input.close()
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are a few issues.

1. Nowhere in your posted code do you define `str`. What's more, [`str` is a built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).
2. It is not correct to do `input.row`. You do not need to qualify `row` here.
3. There is no string method `.contains()`. You can use `.find()` or `.index()`
4. You never actually write anything with `writer.writerow()`.

Instead you should do something like:

```
# ... 
    mystr = row.split('@')[1]
    if not mystr.find('Amsterdam'):
        writer.writerow(row)
# ...
```

Aside: You might generally do a bit more debugging before posting a question here.